# ERROR MESSAGES DOES NOT DISPLAY

Tags: php, mysql, forms

i have a php file that process my registration form however it does not display the error messages if the form has discrepancies (blank fields, etc.). Also, the captcha validation is not working.

This is the php code that process the form.

```
<?php
//Start session
session_start();

//Include database connection details
require_once('connect.php');

//Array to store validation errors
$errmsg_arr = array();

//Validation error flag
$errflag = false;

//Connect to mysql server
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if(!$link) {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
}

//Select database
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
if(!$db) {
    die("Unable to select database");
}

//Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}

//Sanitize the POST values
$username = clean($_POST['username']);
$password = clean($_POST['password']);
$cpassword = clean($_POST['cpassword']);
$nickname = clean($_POST['nickname']);
$email = clean($_POST['email']);
$code = clean($_POST['code']);

//Input Validations
if($username == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Username missing';
    $errflag = true;
}
if($password == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Password missing';
    $errflag = true;
}
if($cpassword == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Confirm Password missing';
    $errflag = true;
}
if($nickname == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'nickname missing';
    $errflag = true;
}
if($email == '') {
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Email Address missing';
    $errflag = true;
}
if( strcmp($password, $cpassword) != 0 ) {
    echo "Password Do not match";
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Passwords do not match';
    $errflag = true;
}




  include("../captcha/securimage.php");
  $img = new Securimage();
  $valid = $img->check($_POST['code']);

  if($valid == true) {
  echo "<center>Thanks, you entered the correct code.</center>";
  } else {
  echo "<center>Sorry, the code you entered was invalid.";
  }





//Check for duplicate login ID
if($login != '') {
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM employee_login WHERE username='$username'";
    $result = mysql_query($qry);
    if($result) {
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            $errmsg_arr[] = 'Username already in use';
            $errflag = true;
        }
        @mysql_free_result($result);
    }
    else {
        die("Query failed");
    }
}

//If there are input validations, redirect back to the registration form
if($errflag) {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    session_write_close();
    header("location: ../register.php");
    exit();
}

//Create INSERT query
$qry = "INSERT INTO employee_login(username, password, email, nickname) VALUES('$username','".md5($_POST['password'])."','$email','$nickname')";
$result = @mysql_query($qry);

//Check whether the query was successful or not
if($result) {
    header("location: ../registergood.php");
    exit();
}else {
    die("Query failed");
}
?>
```

What might be wrong?

Comment: 1) Don't SHOUT 2) Narrow down the problem. Don't just post a huge block of code and say "it's not working. figure out why."

Comment: Every developer (even newbie) should learn how to debug your own code **yourself**. Remove all `@`, turn on errors output, set error_reporting level to E_ALL...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's not displaying your error messages because at no point in the code you've provided do you output those messages to the user. You store them in an array and later a session variable, but that's it.

Comment: how can i be able to retrieve / display it on the original register.php (my registration form)

Comment: @PHPNewbie: keep the code that processes the form data and the one that outputs the form together. In this case you wouldn't have questions like "how to pass the data between scripts"